# Standard function for comparing regression (supervised learning) algorithms

Tags: regression, supervised-learning

I would like to do some Monte Carlo based comparisons of regression methods.

I am looking for a general contnuous function or class of functions to generate training and testing data sets.

The general idea is given some function f, generate a random set of input values X, and outputs Y = f(X) + e, where e is random noise.

One idea I had was to use a radial basis function network to represent f, then you could generate a large number of different functions (by drawing random centres and weights).

Does this sound reasonable, any better ideas?